# Need help in confirming the answer to a combinatorics question?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need help to confirm my answer for the following question

"There is an alphabet of size 40 and this alphabet is used for forming messages in a communication system. If 10 of these alphabets can be used only as the first or last symbols in the message and the rest 30 can be used anywhere, how many messages can be formed if repetition is allowed, The length of the messages is 25 symbols?"

I came up with the following solution for this question = 30^(23) * 1600

Comment: I am sorry to miss that, the length of the messages can be 25 symbols

Comment: If all messages must have length exactly $25$, your answer is correct. I would not call it a solution, since no explanation is given, but it is easy to guess what the underlying thinking was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remaining 30 letters can be used anywhere then you are correct. In this case you have 40 letters available for the first and last symbols and only 30 available for the 23 symbols in between. So, the count is $40^2 \cdot 30^{23}$.

What johannesvalks is answering is if the first and last symbols must come from these 10 special characters. In this case you have 10 letters available for the first and last symbols and still only 30 30 available for the 23 symbols in between. So, the count is $10^2 \cdot 30^{23}$.

Answer (score 0):

Only 10 for the first and the last and 30 for the innerpart thus

$$
10 + 10 \times 10 + 10 \times 30 \times 10 + 10 \times 30^2 \times 10 + 10 \times 30^3 \times 10 + \cdots + 10 \times 30^8 \times 10
$$

Thus

$$
10 + 100 \sum_{k=0}^{8} 30^k = 10 + 100 \frac{30^9 - 30}{30-1}.
$$

---

For $25$ symbols we get

$$
10 \times 30^{23} \times 10
$$

Comment: I have updated the problem statement, can you check and tell

Comment: Yes I have missed the 25 symbols... Then it is indeed different...

Comment: I think that the 1600 is not correct, only 10 symbols can be used as first or last - so it would be 100...

Comment: There are lots of cases, like the 1st symbol can be a special symbol, or last can be a special symbol or none or both won't you take that into account??